# How To Code a Basic Questionnaire

Tags: android

I am new to Android and have the SDK up and running fine.  I am looking for some model code to make an app with a 15-item questionnaire (yes/no) and score it.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can find a handy tutorial for creating a quiz app in Android [here](http://maxood-android-corner.blogspot.com/2010/08/developing-quiz-app-on-android.html).

Alternatively, the app you are describing is simple enough to be created using Google App Inventor (no coding required). You can find a tutorial using that method [here](http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu/learn/tutorials/quizme/quizme.html).