# How I can display the contents of the following json

Tags: java, android, json

I am really new in android app development. I am developing an android app in which I need to display a list of questions one after the other to the user with the help of a next button. When the user clicks next button, the next question appears together with its list of options to choose from. The questions and options are retrieved from a `MySQL` database with `PHP` and the response is in `JSON` format shown below

```
{
"questions": [
    {
        "q_id": "18",
        "qtext": "The largest liability appearing in the book of a commercial bank is",
        "option_1": "cash",
        "option_2": "deposits",
        "option_3": "loans and advances",
        "option_4": "capital and reserves",
        "option_5": "treasury bills"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "7",
        "qtext": "A commercial bank is unique in that it is only the institution that",
        "option_1": "makes loans to private people and businessmen",
        "option_2": "accept deposits",
        "option_3": "can store peoples' valuables",
        "option_4": "can transfer money from one place to another for its customers",
        "option_5": "saves money through the granting of credits"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "3",
        "qtext": "When elasticity is zero, the demand curve is",
        "option_1": "Perfectly elastic",
        "option_2": "Perfectly inelastic",
        "option_3": "Concave",
        "option_4": "Downward slopping",
        "option_5": "Circular"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "5",
        "qtext": "Inferior goods are referred to in Economics as goods",
        "option_1": "Whose quality is low",
        "option_2": "Consumed by very poor people",
        "option_3": "Whose consumption falls when consumers' income rises",
        "option_4": "Which satisfy only the basic needs",
        "option_5": "None of the above"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "4",
        "qtext": "The following is NOT a reason for the existence of small firms",
        "option_1": "Scale of production is limited by size of the market",
        "option_2": "Expansion brings diminishing returns",
        "option_3": "Large firms can carter for wide markets",
        "option_4": "Small firms can provide personal services",
        "option_5": "All of the above"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "10",
        "qtext": "If a company doubles all its inputs and discovers that its output more than doubles, we can say that the company is experiencing",
        "option_1": "Increasing Marginal utility",
        "option_2": "Dis-economies of scale",
        "option_3": "Increasing costs",
        "option_4": "Constant returns to scale",
        "option_5": "Increasing returns to scale"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "17",
        "qtext": "Which of the following statements is true?",
        "option_1": "A proportional tax is one which takes from high income people a higher fraction of their income than it takes for low income people",
        "option_2": "taxes on commodities of services which can be shifted elsewhere are usually called direct taxes",
        "option_3": "The sole proprietor is a legal entity",
        "option_4": "the influence of demand on price will be smallest on the short run",
        "option_5": "the cost of production is the most important determining factor of supply in the long run"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "1",
        "qtext": "Suppose that the equilibrium price of an article is $5.00 but the government fixes the price by law at $4.00, the supply will be",
        "option_1": "The same as equilibrium supply",
        "option_2": "Greater than equilibrium supply",
        "option_3": "Less than the equilibrium supply",
        "option_4": "Determined later by government",
        "option_5": "None of these"
    }
],
"success": 1
   }
```

Please how can I display these questions and their set of options one after the other with the help of a next button.

I will really appreciate your help or if you can show me any link showing a tutorial on how to accomplish this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: sure the json is a valid one

Comment: This question was already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975416/how-to-code-a-basic-questionnaire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one class `Question` with this structure:

```
class Question{
    String id;
    String qtext;
    String opt1;
    String opt2;
    String opt3;
    String opt4;
    String opt5;

    public Question (id, ques, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5){
        this.id = id;
        this.qtext = ques;
        this.opt1 = opt1;
        this.opt2 = opt2;
        this.opt3 = opt3;
        this.opt4 = opt4;
        this.opt5 = opt5; 
    }
}
```

Parse your response data to class as:

```
    List<Question> queList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
    int n = jArray.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // GET INDIVIDUAL JSON OBJECT FROM JSON ARRAY
        JSONObject jo = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        // RETRIEVE EACH JSON OBJECT'S FIELDS
        String id = jo.getString("id");
        String qtext = jo.getString("qtext");
        String opt1 = jo.getString("option1");
        String opt2 = jo.getString("option2");
        String opt3 = jo.getString("option3");
        String opt4 = jo.getString("option4");
        String opt5 = jo.getString("option5");

        Question que = new Question(id, qtext, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5);
        queList.add(que);
    }
```

So you can use it from list after parsing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mystic Magic. The second part of your explanation you gave will be in the activity class am using to display the questions one after the other? In the class Question, what about getters and setters for each of the variables? Do I need them?

Comment: The second part will be where you get the response (So, in activity of course.) And whether you require getter setter will depend on your requirement. I think you won't need setter as you are already setting all variables of class when you create its object. If your requirement is to get specific variable, yo can create getters. @wally

Comment: Please now am having an exception saying org.json.JSONException: Value (myjson) of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject. What should I do? I will really appreciate your assistance. @Mystic Magic

Comment: Please can you show me how I can use 'if' from list after parsing? Thanks in advance. @MysticMagic

Comment: @wally what do you mean by **how I can use 'if' from list after parsing**? I am not able to understand.

Comment: ...I was actually referring to your comment after the second part of your response to my answer(the code). In that comment you wrote that 'So you can use if from list after parsing. Hope this helps'. That comment is the one am asking about. Thanks.

Comment: I was actually referring to your comment after the second part of your response to my answer(the code). In that comment you wrote that 'So you can use if from list after parsing. Hope this helps'. That comment is the one am asking about. Thanks. @Mystic Magic

Comment: sorry, that was **So you can use it from list after parsing**.. Typo mistake @wally :)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. After trying to for many hours, I eventually figured it out that maybe you meant to write 'it' :). Thanks for your help. @Mystic Magic

Comment: Ok :) @wally sorry for that typo. json parsing Problem solved? :)

Comment: Yeah the problem is solved for now. But I have some other questions one or two, please is it possible to move this to chat? @Mystic Magic

Comment: I am not able to do so, as you have only 1 reputation and not allowed to use chat :( @wally

Comment: I see. That's true. I tried it now also and I got that same response. Anyway my questions is that in my activity class, I have another class called (ListQuestions which extends AsyncTask). In this class I have the usual methods-doInBackground from which I returned json string, onPostExecute inside which I did the json parsing and store the objects in my Question class. Now what I want to do is to use the result in my activity's onCreate so i can display the list contents one after the other with the next button. How can I implement that? Thanks again @Mystic Magic

Comment: Sorry @wally not able to understand. It would be better if you accept this answer for this question and open a new question :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need a TextView for your question and several CheckBoxes for your answers.

I would store the questions and answers from your JSON-Object in an ArrayList with a Questions-Object (members: questionID, question, answer1, answer2,..)

Then you need a Button, where you implement an OnClickListener. And whenever the user clicks the button you change the text of the TextView and the CheckBoxes to the next Question-Object in your list.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks xandi. This is what am planning to do as in displaying each of the questions in a textview while the options set are going to be in a radio group consisting of 5 radio buttons. Please can you show a little bit code on how to implement your explanation? Thanks in advance. @xandi

Comment: Hallo, i would implement it like this.           int index = 0;
        List<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // fill list with JSON Objects
        mButton.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextfeld.setText(list.get(index).getQuestion);
                mAnswer1.setText(list.get(index).getAnswer1);
                mAnswer2.setText(list.get(index).getAnswer2);
                // for all other options
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json, questions is an array and each element of this array consists question id, ques test and this question options.

Now here options maybe less or more than 4 which starts as option_1, option_2 ..., so here you should have to apply a loop to get the options like:

```
String keyHeader = "option_"
int optionNumber = 1;
boolean loopEnds = false;
while(!loopEnds ){

if(jsonObject.has(keyHeader+String.valueof(optionNumber)){

  //read the option and save it like:
jsonObject.getString(keyHeader+String.valueof(optionNumber));
optionNumber++;
}
else loopEnds  = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("Your jsons Response String");

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("questions");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String Q_id = c.getString("q_id");
                    String Qtest = c.getString("QText");
                    String Qop2 = c.getString("option_1");


                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```